# GoldMine 8.0 API GMW_LoadAPI fails

Tags: visual-c++, goldmine

`GMW_LoadAPI` is failing to load and returns `--4`. I checked all the parameters, they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application user doesn't have rights on folder where goldmine licence file is.

Answer (score 0):

From the GoldMine API manual:

> GMW_LoadBDE Return Values Return
>   Description 1 Success 0 API already
>   loaded
>   -1 API failed to load
>   -2 Cannot find license file
>   -3 Cannot load license file
>   -4 Cannot validate the license file username/password
>   -5 Invalid GoldDir
>   -6 Invalid CommonDir
>   -7 Failed to allocate the needed TLS slot
>   -8 General Failure
>   -9 No access to specified contact set for this user

Looks like your username or password is incorrect.

Also worth exploring is whether or not you're running the GoldMine EXE over the netwrok or locally.  The latter is highly recommended.